# pip hangs after upgrade to 7.1.2 on Windows x64

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using the Anaconda distribution for my programming needs in python (Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)) - running under Windows 10. After upgrading the pip package manager to the latest version, pip hangs whenever I call it. It simply stays mute, leaving me with an empty cursor, and my only option is to kill the process. I tried to uninstall it manually (of course I can't use pip to uninstall itself if it's not going to run to start with), and reinstall with get-pip.py, but apparently to no avail. I restarted Spyder, tried from a command window, rebooted the computer and all of that, tried all variants such as pip2.exe and pip2.7.exe; it didn't make any difference. Mind that it does not seem to be a configuration issue, at least not in the sense that the PATH would be uncorrectly set - the executable is found, but just hangs.
Does anyone recognize this problem? 
pip.exe is 95.8 kB - does that sound right?

I appreciate any help. Kind regards,

Peter.
EDIT: the previous version, which seemed to work, was 7.0.

Comment: There seems to be a workaround for starting pip. Have a look here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724228/pip-hangs-in-windows-7